# Why operator LIMIT does not work correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote the next query SQL for getting last comments with re-comments:

```
SELECT c.*, ar.ArticleName, ar.idArticle, du.DetailToUsersName, du.DetailToUsersPhoto, COUNT(c.idCommentToArticle) AS CNT, CASE WHEN d.Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.Count END AS CountLikes 
FROM commenttoarticle c 

INNER JOIN (SELECT CommentToArticlePID FROM commenttoarticle 
GROUP BY CommentToArticlePID 
ORDER BY CommentToArticlePID LIMIT 3) AS articleComments 
USING (CommentToArticlePID) 

LEFT JOIN article ar ON c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = ar.idArticle 
LEFT JOIN detailtousers du ON du.idDetailToUsers = c.CommentToArticleIdUser 
LEFT JOIN `likes` d ON (d.IdNote = c.idCommentToArticle AND d.LikeType = 6) 

WHERE c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11 
GROUP BY c.idCommentToArticle
```

So, why operator `LIMIT 3` in sub-query select does not work? Now this query shows all rows from table  `commenttoarticle`

I seem that need do somethink like as:

```
SELECT...
FROM (select * from commenttoarticle commenttoarticle c INNER JOIN
            (SELECT distinct(CommentToArticlePID)
              FROM commenttoarticle b
                ORDER BY CommentToArticlePID
                   LIMIT  2) AS commenttoarticle USING (CommentToArticlePID)) as c

          LEFT JOIN article ar ON c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = ar.idArticle...
```

**Dump table commenttoarticle:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `commenttoarticle` (
  `idCommentToArticle` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CommentToArticleTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CommentToArticleIdArticle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CommentToArticleComment` text NOT NULL,
  `CommentToArticleIdUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CommentToArticlePID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCommentToArticle`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idCommentToArticle_UNIQUE` (`idCommentToArticle`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=59 ;


INSERT INTO `commenttoarticle` (`idCommentToArticle`, `CommentToArticleTime`, `CommentToArticleIdArticle`, `CommentToArticleComment`, `CommentToArticleIdUser`, `CommentToArticlePID`) VALUES
(29, 0, 11, 'продажам?\nИнтересует не мега-звезда, а именно предметный, руками умеющий продавать сам и помогающий выстраивать это бизнесам.', 459, 0),
(30, 0, 11, '2', 459, 0),
(31, 0, 11, '3', 459, 0),
(36, 0, 11, '3.1', 459, 31),
(37, 1413822798, 11, 'also facing that prob. on the plteform of win 7', 459, 29),
(38, 0, 11, ' here i dont have internet connection.. @Samint Sinha thanks ill check it out maybe tomorrow.', 459, 29),
(39, 0, 11, ' Select max id and you will have dhe last row returned', 459, 29),
(32, 0, 11, '4', 459, 0),
(44, 1414354324, 11, 'How to do', 456, 29),
(45, 1414354469, 11, 'sfsfsf', 456, 29),
(46, 1414354708, 11, 'dddd', 456, 29),
(47, 1414357761, 11, 'sfsfs', 456, 0),
(57, 1414370833, 39, 'kkkppppppp', 456, 0),
(49, 1414358233, 11, 'VSF\nSFSF', 456, 0),
(50, 1414359589, 11, 'How to do', 456, 0),
(51, 1414359660, 11, 'sfsfsdf', 456, 0),
(52, 1414361057, 11, 'SDFSF', 456, 0),
(53, 1414364023, 11, 'dsfdsjfsifmsi', 456, 0),
(54, 1414364031, 11, 'sdfdskjfnskf', 456, 52),
(55, 1414364034, 11, 'sdfdskjfnskf', 456, 52),
(56, 1414364044, 11, 'fndsdfnsofosfi', 456, 52),
(58, 1414370841, 39, 'dfgdfgdgdgdgdgdfgdgdfg', 456, 0);
```

**Dump table article:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `idArticle` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ArticleName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleDescription` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleText` text NOT NULL,
  `ArticleToUserID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArticleCategory` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleView` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleCountry` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ArticlePhoto` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ArticleCity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idArticle`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idArticle_UNIQUE` (`idArticle`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=50 ;
```

Comment: What does `CommentToArticlePID` hold? Right now your are grouping and limiting on that column, but not using it anywhere else.

Comment: Maybe my query is wrong, so can remove GROUP BY `CommentToArticlePID`  at second query, but is not solution

Comment: No we can not remove  `GROUP BY CommentToArticlePID`, because then we can not get children rows

Comment: What is stored in that column, without proper information, we'll keep shooting in the dark.

Comment: Last try, please update your queston with actual data (from all tables). There's no way of saying what is going wrong without that.

Comment: Please, look at updated question

Comment: Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By constructing a self join on comments yuo're not limiting but multiply the result.
What you need is a single subquery on comments table

```
SELECT c.*, ar.ArticleName,
    ar.idArticle, du.DetailToUsersName,
    du.DetailToUsersPhoto, COALECSE(SUM(d.count), 0)
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM 
         commenttoarticle
     WHERE
         CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11
     ORDER BY
         CommentToArticlePID, idCommentToArticle DESC
     LIMIT 3
    ) c
LEFT JOIN 
    article ar
    ON c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = ar.idArticle 
LEFT JOIN
    detailtousers du
    ON du.idDetailToUsers = c.CommentToArticleIdUser 
LEFT JOIN
    likes d
    ON (d.IdNote = c.idCommentToArticle AND d.LikeType = 6)
GROUP BY
    c.idCommentToArticle
```

I have made the assumption that a comment can have multiple entries in the likes table, otherwise the subquery and the group by is not necesarry.

Answer (score 1):

```
The USING(column_list) clause names a list of columns that must exist in both tables.
```

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

`CommentToArticlePID` is not in your first table.

Also, what is the point of joining a single column?  Yes, if you want to limit, this might be applicable, but then why us LIMIT?

Comment: I need use `LIMIT` that show only some last rows with all children rows(`PID`). The join's need only for parent comments. If you can, explain your answer, please, I am not sure about `CommentToArticlePID`

Comment: @AllenDegrud.  Not really sure on what you are doing.  I like using `ON` instead of `USING`, so I will describe it that way.  You are joining derived table `articleComments` to `commenttoarticle` on articleComments.CommentToArticlePID=commenttoarticle.CommentToArticlePID.  Does CommentToArticl exist in both tables.  Also, you are grouping on CommentToArticlePID, so you only get one result, thus the LIMIT does nothing.

Comment: Hm,can you modify my query with `ON` instead `USING` ? May be I will understand my error?

Comment: I tried remove `GROUP` and `USING`, then query is right, but `LIMIT` does not work

Comment: It's no error, it's another way of writing join conditions (which is only possible if the columns have the same name in both tables)

Comment: So, any ways. Maybe change query?

Comment: As i commented at your OP, you must provide more information. Edit you're question appropiatly and maybe I'm able to give an answer