# Duplicate column name SQL - need change alias?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written SQL query with a INNER JOIN and Sub-query:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       ar.ArticleName, 
       ar.idArticle, 
       du.DetailToUsersName, 
       du.DetailToUsersPhoto, 
       COUNT(c.idCommentToArticle) AS CNT, 
       CASE WHEN d.Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.Count END AS CountLikes 
from (select * 
      from commenttoarticle g 
      inner join (select distinct(s.idCommentToArticle) 
                  from commenttoarticle s 
                  order by s.CommentToArticlePID limit 3) as gh) as c 

LEFT JOIN article ar ON c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = ar.idArticle 
LEFT JOIN detailtousers du ON du.idDetailToUsers = c.CommentToArticleIdUser 
LEFT JOIN `likes` d ON (d.IdNote = c.idCommentToArticle AND d.LikeType = 6) 
WHERE c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11 
GROUP BY c.idCommentToArticle 
ORDER BY c.idCommentToArticle DESC
```

So, I get error:

> Duplicate column name 'idCommentToArticle'

I can not find where the duplication is?

Comment: Probably because of the select * of the derived table c

Comment: Hm, what I must specify instead `*` all fields name?

Comment: The duplication is the result of the inner query directly after the 1st FROM.  You are joining `commenttoarticle g` to the subquery which returns only idCommentToArticle.  When you do `SELECT *` on this it takes all the fields from `g` and your subquery, and attempts to alias the fieldnames for the outer query `c`.  This is the point where it cannot create the alias because it is in both.  When you try to reference `c.idCommentToArticle` it cannot tell whether you mean from table alias `g` or the subquery.

Comment: I would suggest that your `LIMIT` be pushed to the outer query.  Putting it in your inner query means that your are limiting only to the first 3 records of the `commenttoarticle` table, irrespective of what values are in those rows. Doing this means that you are NOT using any of your filter criteria from the outer query.  In designing a `LIMIT` query, you would typically filter out all the rows not required, before applying the `LIMIT`.  Then `JOIN` onto matching tables to finalise the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RADAR has suggested, your inner query joins don't seem to be complete. And I see from comments that once you place the JOIN condition in, then you lose all data.  I think this is because neither part of the subqueries were doing what they were supposed to do.

Here is my attempt at a total solution (note, without dataset and table definition I can't show it working). OK, so you have asked the question again over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585516/return-all-rows-from-sub-query-sql) and provided a [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbd82a/22), I have updated with a working version, but minus the additional JOIN tables, since they are not defined.

```
SELECT c.*, 
       ar.ArticleName, 
       ar.idArticle, 
       du.DetailToUsersName, 
       du.DetailToUsersPhoto, 
       COUNT(c.idCommentToArticle) AS CNT, 
       CASE WHEN d.Count IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE d.Count END AS CountLikes 
FROM commenttoarticle c   -- one layer of subquery not required.
INNER JOIN (select  s.idCommentToArticle, s.CommentToArticlePID -- added both the id and the parent id
            FROM commenttoarticle s 
            WHERE s.CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11 -- moved to inner query, instead of outer query
            ORDER BY s.idCommentToArticle DESC limit 3) as gh 
        ON c.idcommenttoarticle = gh.idcommenttoarticle   -- add join condition
        OR c.idcommenttoarticle = gh.CommentToArticlePID  -- which matches id and parent id

LEFT JOIN article ar ON c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = ar.idArticle 
LEFT JOIN detailtousers du ON du.idDetailToUsers = c.CommentToArticleIdUser 
LEFT JOIN `likes` d ON (d.IdNote = c.idCommentToArticle AND d.LikeType = 6) 

GROUP BY c.idCommentToArticle 
ORDER BY c.idCommentToArticle DESC
```

But let me explain a little further, the following code from your original query was selecting the top 3 idCommentToArticlePID,

```
(select * 
  from commenttoarticle g 
  inner join (select distinct(s.idCommentToArticle) 
            from commenttoarticle s 
            order by s.CommentToArticlePID limit 3) as gh)
```

but then because there was no `ON` specified the 3 records were then joined to every single record from the `g` reference. This resulted in the full dataset being returned.

And then you you specified `WHERE c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11` this filtered the result set back down again to something that looked correct.

When you then added the `ON` (as per @RADAR's suggestion) the inner query did not contain any values that matched the `WHERE c.CommentToArticleIdArticle = 11` filter and thus you lost all your results.  If you move this filter into the inner query as shown above, then these will work together and not conflict.

Within the `JOIN` condition, you indicate that you want both the matching articles and their parents, so I added both to the return of the inner query, and checked for either in the join condition.

Also I think the whole `g` table reference is redundant and can be removed. You should be able to access this table directly as `c`.

I also have some concerns about the `GROUP BY` and `COUNT (c.idCommentToArticle)` - there seem a little strange, but I have no supporting context (ie data examples), so they may be correct.  If you still have issues, I would comment the `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` statements out, and test to see what data you are getting, before adding these back in.

Comment: Is not correct result at any type of your example. I have checked. The first query returns all rows, and with condition WHERE.

Comment: @AllenDegrud - I was working on the update just then. do you want to try again? see SQL Fiddle near top of answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify  in the alias table query c

```
select g.* from commenttoarticle g
```

instead of

```
select * from commenttoarticle g
```

Also you should specify Join condition to limit the rows to 3 as per your intention, with out the ON clause it will be like a cross join.

```
select g.* from commenttoarticle g 
inner join (select distinct(s.idCommentToArticle) from commenttoarticle s order by s.CommentToArticlePID limit 3) as gh
     on g.idcommenttoarticle = gh.idcommenttoarticle
```

Comment: @allendegrud, add join condition like I mentioned

Comment: Yes, it is a right answer. But if I specify `Join condition`, I dont get rows, where `PID > 0`, only first 3 rows `WHERE PID = 0`, So, I need get first rows PID and PID'S rows.

Comment: I answered about `PID, ID` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575283/why-operator-limit-does-not-work-correctly But nobody could not help me

Comment: @AllenDegrud add pid> 0 also to this limit query itself

Comment: I need get latest parents rows with a all child's rows, limited by parent's rows. For example: there are rows with **ID**: `1,2,3,4,5`. `ID = 3` have a children's `3.1, 3.2`. So, If I use LIMIT 4, I need get: `1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 4`.

Comment: @AllenDegrud, can you create sql fiddle and show us expected output